# Highly customizing the look and feel of a List View

Tags: 2013, list-view, css, view-styles

I've been given a task to allow a user to add a 'Vacancy' web part to a page.

The webpart will be basically a list of all vacancies from various regions.

This is the desired final product...

[image]

And this is a view I have gotten so far..

[image]

It seems like it's pretty close, in terms of the data Im showing, obviously its the styling I need to achieve.

Is it possible to somehow change the styling of this view to match that of the mock-up? How would one begin to crack open this view and changing the look and feel?
Or would I need to go a different approach? And if so, what would be the best approach?

Comment: Please tag version of the SharePoint with the question.

Comment: Hmmm. You should try looking at the Client Side Rendering (JSLink). It does have the support of modifying this view with help of JavaScript. Take a look at this thread: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/142989/should-we-consolidate-all-form-customization-javascript-into-one-file/142999#142999  You need to consider only `View` option for setting this view.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can complete this using JSLink. JSLink is a property that controls rendering of fields, items and even Web Parts through a JavaScript file. It will overwrite  supply a header and footer and then a JavaScript method (function pointer) to execute for each list item.
Please look at this [post](http://www.sharepointnutsandbolts.com/2013/01/using-jslink-to-change-ui-of-sharepoint_20.html) for more details.

Example how to overwrite item, footer and header for list view:

```
// anonymous self-executing function to setup JSLink templates on page load..
(function () {
    var overrideCtx = {};
    overrideCtx.Templates = {};

    overrideCtx.Templates.Header = "html for header";
    overrideCtx.Templates.Item = "item html";
    overrideCtx.Templates.Footer = "html for footer";

    overrideCtx.BaseViewID = 1;
    overrideCtx.ListTemplateType = "template number";

    SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(overrideCtx);
})();
...
```

Comment: Thanks Andrey, I ended up going this route and pretty much making good progress, thanks! :)